# Integer intrinsics are undefined

Tags: cuda

**E0020 identifier "__ffs" is undefined**

Same for all the various integer intrinsics.

The code that fails (it's a method definition; the class defines x,y,z):

```
__device__ uint32 lowbit()
{
    if (x) return __ffs(x);
    if (y) return 32 + __ffs(y);
    if (z) return 64 + __ffs(z);
    return 96;
}
```

I also tried this (everything works until I add the **__ffs** line:

```
__global__ void addKernel(int* c, const int* a, const int* b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] += a[i] + b[i];
    int foo = __ffs(i);
}
```

A previous question asked about intellisence. In my case, the nvcc compiler also doesn't see them.

According to the CUDA docs:

1.9. Integer Intrinsics
This section describes integer intrinsic functions that are only supported in device code. To use these functions you do not need to include any additional header files in your program.

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019, CUDA 11.2.0

Comment: E0020 is a visual studio error not an nvcc error. Are you really doing this in a .cu file in a correctly set up CUDA project?

Comment: Yes, it's a .h file included by a .cu file based on a new CUDA project from the VS wizard. Prior to adding the line, the code compiled and ran on my device.

But it is an interesting point that E0020 is a VS error. Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: In VS, there are two logs to be aware of, the error log and the console log. My recommendation in the future if you are asking about a VS build failure, include the complete console log that resulted from the build command. This will give others the best ability to help you. Extracting a single portion of a single line (if that's what you did) here: `E0020 identifier "__ffs" is undefined` is less useful. If you actually pulled that out of the error log (where there would often only be 1 line like that) then you may be confused by Intellisense errors, depending on log setting/dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is odd indeed. I added the following line as an experiment:

```
#define __CUDACC__
```

That fixed it, but gave me this warning:

```
warning C4005: '__CUDACC__': macro redefinition
```

I didn't really want to leave it like that, without a clear understanding of what __CUDACC__ is really doing.

What is odd is that when I removed the #define **CUDACC**, the problem didn't come back. Now it all works. Magic. Or perhaps Visual Studio doing something silently for me. Worries me when Microsoft does that kind of thing, but this time I won't complain. :)